# Make GroupOrbits recognise same orbit

Tags: group-theory

When going through a list of elements, `GroupOrbits` usually recognises if the orbit of an element has been calculated already and will skip it in that case to avoid repetitions. For example,

```
GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup[2],{1}] == GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup[2],{1,2}]
```

will result in `True` (because `2` is in the orbit of `1`).

However, if I define

```
a = {{1,1},{1,2}}
b = {{2,1},{2,2}}
```

the sets `GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup[2],{a}]` and `GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup[2],{b}]` are practically the same (as sets, in mathematical notation: `{(1,1),(1,2)}={(1,2),(1,1)}` etc.), but aren't treated as the same by Mathematica. How can I achieve that the output of `GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup[2],{a,b}]` doesn't add one more orbit?

Secondary question: How does Mathematica handle an input of the form {...}? As a list, as a tuple, or as a set? And how can all these types be distinguished? For example, If I have a list or a tuple, how can I pass it to Mathematica as a set (and the other way round)?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing just `GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup[2], a]` (without the curly braces)? Because in that case the two yield the same result.

Comment: Yes, I want the orbit of `{{1,1},{1,2}}` (as a set), not the respective orbits of the two elements `{1,1}` and `{1,2}`.

Comment: Instead of `b`, I could of course write `ReverseSort@b`, that is `GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup[2],{a,ReverseSort@b}]`, but this requires the knowledge of `b`. It would be nice to have that done automatically because the above example is just a minimal example.